# Diagnosing AWS Elastic Block Storage perfomance

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, database-performance

We have an EC2 (m4.2xlarge in us-east-1) based PostgreSQL database that occasionally (regularly last week) get's clogged and performance is badly affected. We've already troubleshooting several related configurations, usage and metrics, we we seem to still have some minor spikes during heavy db usage.

Trying to find out what could be the remaining constraint, everything seems to boil down to hard drives (EBS volumes) performance but, since EBS provides lots of volume related metrics, I don't really know if they are within safe limits or they are being maxed out.

Due to time / growth the db storage is now comprised of 3 EBS gp2 volumes (1, 1 & 2 TB each), which we are aware has less IOPS than a single 4 TB volume, but that'll be fixed when moving to RDS (hopefully within February), but that'll take longer.

Each EBS volume provides the following metrics:

1. R/W Bandwidth
2. R/W Throughput
3. Average Queue Length
4. Time spent idle
5. Average R/W size
6. Average R/W latency
7. Burst balance

Max IOPS are 3000 for the 1TB volumes and 6000 for the 2TB one, but I don't know if it's the sum of read+write, or each of them separate.

What about throughput, latency and idle metrics? What should I look at them?

Here's a summary of the three volume's metrics for the past 3 hours and, around 9AM CLST (Noon UTC in the images) we had our latest "outage".

[image: vol-0db2278ad4ba8a20c]

[image: vol-055778e58548258fb]

[image: vol-0d1cc75abf142e8e5]

Any comments on pinpointing any relevant metrics would be appreciated.